# How can I close linkedin sharing page (means for sharing it opens new page) after sharing completed?

Tags: javascript, href

I want to close linkedin sharing page automatically. I'm using this link to share:

http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&summary:summury&title=title&url=url

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

> There are two methods for sharing content via the REST API.  The API endpoint is the same, regardless of the method you choose — only the format of the request body differs.
>
> 1. Post a comment that includes a URL to the content you wish to share — LinkedIn analyzes the included URL and automatically identifies the title, description, image, etc.
> 2. Share with specific values — You provide the title, description, image, etc., directly via the parameters of the API call.

Comment: thanks  smith.I actually able to share,but after sharing i wanted to close that window automatically(i.e opened window for share from linkdin).

Comment: iam using like this below ............<a>http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;summary:"something else here"&amp;title="title name here"&amp;url="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618937/how-can-i-close-linkedin-sharing-page-means-for-sharing-it-opens-new-page-afte/42618976#42618976"&amp;img="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6MfP.png""</a>